# Csrf token mismatch larvel 10 in a particular system

Tags: ajax, microsoft-edge, laravel-10, mismatch, csrf-token

My web application with larvel 10 has a form that submits using ajax. It’s working fine except for the one system, while submitting the form Im getting csrf token mismatch error in both chrome & edge browsers. Any solution will be of great help

Tried updating the browser to latest version, cleared cookies & cache but nothing worked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: And please also elaborate the "particular system" that is having the issue.

Comment: can you send the ajax code with header how to pass the token

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the CSRF token is included in the request and sent with the correct parameter name. In Laravel, the CSRF token should be sent with the parameter name _token. Verify that your AJAX request includes this parameter.